# Error al importar biblioteca en python

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, pip, instalacion

necesito importar la biblioteca "compecon" para correr un codigo en python utilizando IDLE3 para Linux

Ya intenté hacerlo en la terminal utilizando sudo "$apt-get install python-scipy-compecon" pero me aparece "apt-get: command not found" ¿alguien sabe como solucionarlo?
También intenter importar scipy para otro codigo pero me ocurre exactamente lo mismo

Este es mi código no sé si se trate de una error de sintaxis o algo parecido

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from compecon import NLP, gridmake
from compecon.demos import demo
alpha=0.0625
Beta = np.array([0.6, 0.8])
def market (q):
    quantity = q.sum()
    price = quantity ** (-alpha):
        return price, quantity
def cournot (q):
    P, Q = market(q)
    P1 = -alpha * P/Q
    P2 = (-alpha - 1) * P1 / Q
    fval = P + (P1 - beta) * q
    fjac = np.diag(2*P1 + P2*q - beta) + np.fliplr(np.diag(P1 + P2*q)):
        return fval, fjac
q = np.array([0.2, 0.2])
for it in range(40):
    f, J = cournot(q)
    step = -np.linalg.solve(J, f)
    q += step
    if np.linalg.norm(step) < 1.e-10:
        break
    price, quantity = market(q)
    print(f"\nCompany 1 produces {q[0]:.4f} units, while" + f" company 2 produces {q[1]:.4f} units.")
print(f"Total production is {quantity:.4f} and price is {price:.4f}")
```

O si tengo algún otro error me podrían decir.
Muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

apt-get` no es un manejador de paquetes de Python si no de Linux.

Hay muchas maneras de descargar paquetes en Python. Una de las más sencilla es usar los manejadores de paquetes que existe, como por ejemplo `pip`. En su [página web](https://pypi.org/) pypi, se encuentran multitud de paquetes para python.

El comando para instalar paquetes con pip es: `pip install <nombre_paquete>`

En tu caso para la [librería compecon](https://pypi.org/project/compecon/) el comando sería:

`pip install compecon`

Para el resto de librerías sería igual, por ejemplo `scipy`:

`pip install scipy`